# iPhone - Set UIImage position

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, image

I want to have an image that moves each time I hit a button. It should move a set value of pixels each time.

I was hoping  that image1 now would have a position property, but as far as I can see it doesnt't.

```
  UIImageView *image1=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"indicator"]];
  [self.view addSubview:image1];
...
```

Thank you

EDIT: `UIImageView *image1=[[UIImageView alloc]...`

Comment: `UIImageView *image1=[[UIImageView alloc].... `

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As the other two answers state, you can set the initial position of a UIImageView using a frame (or CGRect). Note that the parameters for the CGRectMake are; x position, y position, x dimension, y dimension.

```
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 100)];
[imgView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:"image.png"]];
```

To move the image each time you press a button, you'll need to update the frame each time the button is pressed. However, the x and y coordinates of a frame are read only, so you'll need to create a new frame like so:

```
CGRect oldFrame = imgView.frame;
CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(oldFrame.origin.x + 10, oldFrame.origin.y, oldFrame.size.width, oldFrame.size.height);
imgView.frame = newFrame;
```

Note that this code moves the image 10 points to the right, (along the x axis).

Comment: Since I am using the first code snippet in ViewDidLoad and the other in the buttonPressed method: how do I reach imgView there, since it is declared in ViewDidLoad?

Comment: You need to declare a UIImageView iVar in your header file, and then allocate it in your viewDidLoad method. Then you'll be able to access if from any method in the class.

Comment: @TeaPow - this is still working on Xcode 12... but the 'ghost' position stays. I read this to believe 'move' meant only 1 image at a time. I've tried various setNewDisplay, etc - but nothing gets rid of the original. Pressing the button just adds new images, not really moving.

Comment: @user3741598 Sounds to me as though you're not modifying the frame of your existing imgView, but rather creating a new UIImageView every time. Sidenote, I've never had somebody tag me in an answer made over 8 years ago. :)

Comment: Thanks. Tagged you because some SO people get upset if people open new questions when there are existing questions. I'm using the same code you supplied, just replacing with my variables. The other strange thing: I have code that works great for 'moving' an image if they're created in Storyboard; but fails when the UIImageView is created with code.

Answer (score 2):

you need an imageview to display an UIImage.

```
UIImage *image1=[UIImage imageNamed:@"indicator.png"];

UIImageView *iv = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,10,100,100)];
iv.image = image1;
[self.view addSubView:iv];
[image1 release];
[iv release];
```

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. But how do I set the position of the rectangle?

Comment: by changing values of `x,y` - cgrect(x,y,dx,dy)

Comment: sure u can. `iv.center = CGPointMake(x,y);`

Answer (score 0):

You can set the frame of the UIImageView:

```
UIImageView* imgv= [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 120, 120)];
imgv.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
```

Here you will have to set the position of frame by trial and error.